# How to use linq to sql to select one column from row

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am using this C# with linq to sql:

```
string currentLabel = from s2f in stream2FieldTypesTable
                      where s2f.s2fID == item.s2fID
                      && (s2f.s2fLabel != item.s2fLabel || s2f.s2fIsRequired != item.s2fIsRequired)
                      select s2f.s2fLabel;
```

I am getting a compiler error saying i can't assign type `System.Linq.IQueryable<string>` to `string`.

I tried this code:

```
string currentLabel = from s2f in stream2FieldTypesTable
                      where s2f.s2fID == item.s2fID
                      && (s2f.s2fLabel != item.s2fLabel || s2f.s2fIsRequired != item.s2fIsRequired)
                      select s2f.s2fLabel.ToString();
```

And that returns the same error. I'm sure this is a simple thing. what am I missing? I just want the first `s2fLabel` that matches the where clause.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actual type of your query will be *IEnumerable*. LINQ has a concept of [deffered execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx), in order to get you query actually exectuted you need to call a method that will iterate over *IEnumerable*:

```
    string currentLabel = (from s2f in stream2FieldTypesTable
                          where s2f.s2fID == item.s2fID
                          && (s2f.s2fLabel != item.s2fLabel || s2f.s2fIsRequired != item.s2fIsRequired)
                          select s2f.s2fLabel)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

For getting exact one instanse it can be *FirstOrDefault()* method or *SignleOrDefault()* or just *First()* or *Single()*. The only difference is that methods without "OrDefault()" will throw an exception if enumeration will not satisfy their expectations, and methods with "OrDefault()" will just return null.

**Edit**

The dirrerence between *Single* and *First* is that *Single* expects **exact one** element in the collection and *First* expects **at least** one element.

Comment: What's the difference between `Single()`, `First()`, and `FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: The return type is the salient factor here, not deferred execution.

Comment: What do you mean under "salient factor"?

Answer (score 2):

```
 int id =Convert.ToInt32(db.Table.Single(x => x.Id == id_factor).Id);
```

Comment: This doesn't appear related to the question, but even if it was, this question is nearly four years old and already has a number of good answers, one of which is already accepted. If you're hunting for rep points, this isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` instead of (or in addition to) `ToString()`.

`First` and `FirstOrDefault` return a single record, rather than a collection of records, which is what your first query does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var result = (from s2f in stream2FieldTypesTable
                      where s2f.s2fID == item.s2fID
                      && (s2f.s2fLabel != item.s2fLabel || s2f.s2fIsRequired != item.s2fIsRequired)
                      select s2f.s2fLabel).First();
```

it is need, because your result is

```
IEnumerable<String>
```

Answer (score 1):

All u need to do is Add parenthesis before and after uour LINQ then use .FirstOrDefault() is u want only single value(which u r bcoz u have string currentLabel).

> string currentLabel = (from s2f in
>   stream2FieldTypesTable
>                         where s2f.s2fID == item.s2fID
>                         && (s2f.s2fLabel != item.s2fLabel || s2f.s2fIsRequired
>   != item.s2fIsRequired)
>                         select s2f.s2fLabel).FirstOrDefault();